# Why didn't Prince Zuko's mother stop the Fire Lord from scarring him?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In Avatar, the Last Airbender we learn how Prince Zuko became scarred and banished. The Fire Lord challenged him to Agni Kai and burned his face for showing disrespect and refusing to fight.

Where was Zuko's mother during these events? Did she try to stop the Fire Lord? I'm looking for a canon answer.

Comment: This can be answered by just watching the rest of the series

Comment: Sorry, my bad. For some reason I thought this happened while she was still there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Princess Ursa left the capital years earlier as part of a deal with

> Prince Ozai, wherein she poisoned Fire Lord Azulon, allowing Ozai to become Fire Lord.

http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Ursa

As revealed in the backstory in the follow-up comic *[The Search](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search)*, she was very unhappy with the arranged marriage, and made that deal in order to escape back to her home village. Additionally, Azulon was planning

> to kill Zuko to punish Ozai for seeking advancement when Prince Iroh's only son died

and Ozai believed

> Zuko to not actually be his genetic son,

all of which was washed away by Princess Ursa taking that deal.